# i want to know if my LSTM model is in : Underfit ? Good Fit ? or Overfit case

Tags: validation, keras, deep-learning, time-series, lstm

I've built an Lstm model here is the structure and when I've plotted the loss and val-loss. This is what I am getting, is this results supposed to be good? Else whats the problem thanks in advance

> Model: "vanilla-LSTM"
>
> Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
>   lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 200)               161600
>   dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 150)               30150
>   dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 24)                3624
>   Total params: 195,374 Trainable params: 195,374 Non-trainable params:
>   0

[Click here for the plot:train loss vs test loss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z65ss.png)

Comment: No, such behaviour doesn't look loke underfit or overfit